Always 'None' with scraping google maps
I scraped a google maps and got few URLs and i wanted to extract few data but i can't

def get_data(path_txt):
    with open(path_txt) as file:
        
        url_to_sc = [url.strip() for url in file.readlines()]
        
    for url in url_to_sc:
        
        response =  requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        
        

        name_element = soup.find('h1', class_='DUwDvf lfPIob')
        print(name_element)

i actually want to get the name but i always get 'None'

What you get from requests.get() is the html of the page. It does not necessarily contain all the tags you see in the "View Page Source" or "inspect element". There may be tags which are generated by JS. Also some web pages dynamically loads the content by api calls.
Print the response.text, make sure that the tag or element you're interested in is present in it. If not it means your case must be the case I describe before. You can use tools like Selenium or Playwright which basically bring up a browser therefore they render the JS and you may see the same structure.
I recommend to locate elements by other methods than class names like 'DUwDvf lfPIob'. Use relative positions or find the closest tag with stable ID. You can use xpath and filter by the "text" of elements.
